# Using partial with groupby and apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble using partial with groupby and apply in Pandas. Perhaps I am not using this right?

```
data = {'a':[1,1,2,2],'b':['Y','Y','N','Y'], 'c':['Y','Y','N','Y']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
def countY(columnName, group): return len(group[group[columnName] == 'Y'])
df.groupby('a').apply(partial(countY, 'b'))
```

**AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '_*module*_'**

```
welcome@welcome-ThinkCentre-Edge72:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> from functools import partial
>>> data = {'a':[1,1,2,2],'b':['Y','Y','N','Y'], 'c':['Y','Y','N','Y']}
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
>>> def countY(columnName, group): return len(group[group[columnName] == 'Y'])
... 
>>> df.groupby('a').apply(partial(countY, 'b'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 420, in apply
    @wraps(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.13.1'
>>>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What Python and Pandas versions are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `functools.partial` here, as you can provide arguments to the function inside the `apply` call.

If your function has as first argument the group (so switch the order of the arguments), then the other arguments in `apply` are passed to the function and in this way you can specify the `columnName` in the apply:

```
In [10]: def countY2(group, columnName):
    ...:    return len(group[group[columnName] == 'Y'])
    ...: 

In [11]: df.groupby('a').apply(countY2, 'b')
Out[11]: 
a
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

The reason it does not work with partial, is that `functools.wraps` does not seem to work together with `functools.partial` (`wraps` is used inside the apply).